# Celery Bulk Execution Stops after 100 Tasks run Successfully

Tags: python, celery

I have the following logic to be executed in Celery:

1. Download a file from AWS S3 using `requests` (max 2 MB)
2. Process the file (approx 100% CPU is used) into an output file
3. Upload the output file to AWS S3 (min 2 MB) (using `boto`)
4. Update a Mongo DB collection (using `pymongo`) pertaining to the file.

Now this process runs nicely and tasks are completed (approx 2 seconds for a task which is acceptable for me given the processing logic as mentioned in point 2 above).

**However, if I send a large number of tasks to be executed (around 5000), Celery hangs after completing about 100 tasks**.

This means that I see no further output on logs. There is no error log, no other kind of log that indicates that Celery has stuck in the logic. It simply doesn't accept any new tasks.

Another thing to note would be that my Celery task is triggered from a request made to my Flask server, so yes, for 5000 Celery tasks 5000 requests are made to my Flask server.

**WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED**

1. Implementing `Batches`
2. Setting timeout to all the requests I make to AWS S3
3. Setting Celery concurrency to 10

None of these solutions worked.

**Question**

How do I configure Celery to successfully complete tasks that may amount to 1 million?

**Additional Information**

Celery version : 4.0.2

Python version : 2.7

Server: Dual core with 8 GB RAM

Message broker : Redis

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"? Process crashes? Exception raised? What is in the log? Run your worker with `-l info` or `-l debug` and look for errors. I have a Celery cluster running few million tasks per day and tens of thousands of those deal with AWS S3. The only problem we ever had was the S3 rate limit reached - that is something you have to deal with eventually, but that should be in the log! So let's first examine the logs...

Comment: Sorry for that, question updated.

Comment: What is your concurrency type?

Comment: I just set the concurrency using the `--concurrency` flag. Not sure about type

Comment: OK, then it is probably the default - the prefork one.